# SQL subconsultas com contador

Tags: sql, group-by

Eu tenho uma tabela assim:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Nome  | Cargo      | Estado          +
+ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Joao  | Estagiário | RJ              +
+ Maria | Analista   | RJ              +
+ Thiago| Gerente    | SP              +
+ Pedro | Analista   | SP              +
+ Joana | Estagiário | MG              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

E gostaria de fazer um select no SQL para obter um resultado assim:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Estado| Estagiário    | Analista  | Gerente   +
+ +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ MG    | 2             | 3         | 1         +
+ RJ    | 1             | 2         | 1         +
+ SP    | 1             | 2         | 3         +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Eu usei a seguinte consulta:

```
select count distinct Cargo
from tabela1
where Cargo in ('Analista')
group by Estado
```

Mas não deu muito certo.

Answer (score 1):

Essa consulta deve funcionar:

```
SELECT ESTADO,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CARGO = "ESTAGIARIO" THEN 1 END) estag,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CARGO = "ANALISTA" THEN 1 END) analista,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CARGO = "GERENTE" THEN 1 END) gerente
FROM suaTabela
GROUP BY ESTADO;
```

Answer (score 0):

pode realizar um pivot.:

```
SELECT Estado, [Estagiário], [Analista], [Gerente]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Estado, 
        Cargo 
    FROM @tabela
) AS t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(Cargo) 
    FOR Cargo IN ([Estagiário], [Analista], [Gerente])
) AS p
```